# Need help to do "mapping" in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, etl

I have a result set/RS1 which looks like this -

```
ColName1,ColName2,ColName3,ColName4... 
a,1,e,c...
b,3,r,p...
```

etc...

RS1 comes from **Server1**. 
ColName[X] are actually real names like ID, Name, Address etc.

There is another result set on **Server2** RS2 which has columns like this -

```
Name,ColumnPosition,ColumnName 
xyz,Col1,NULL
abc,Col4,NULL
asd,Col2,NULL
```

etc.

Now, I want to map each ColumnPosition of RS2 to its corresponding ColumnName in RS1. How do I do that ? Would SQL be enough or do I need to use some ETL tool do to this easily and accurately ?

Expected result sample -

```
Name,ColumnPosition,ColumnName 
xyz,Col1,ColName1
abc,Col4,ColName4
asd,Col2,ColName2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want, but ...

```
CREATE TABLE RS1 (ID INT, [Count] INT, [Amount] INT)

INSERT INTO RS1 VALUES(1,0,2)
INSERT INTO RS1 VALUES(2,3,1)
INSERT INTO RS1 VALUES(3,1,2)

SELECT * FROM RS1

SELECT  t.ID,
  x.ColPos,
  x.ColName,
  x.Value
FROM    RS1 t
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES
        (1, 'Count', t.[Count]),
        (2, 'Amount', t.[Amount])
) x (ColPos, ColName, Value)
```

Comment: okay, let me explain it differently - In RS2, Put ColName1 wherever Col1 occurs in the ColumnPosition column. ColName1 is just a name for a database column. It can be anything, like name, id, date etc. I am trying to make a generalized statement. Does that make sense ?

Comment: I am still not sure what is all this thing about, if you're trying to get the column's name based on the column's position then you can define a computed column with a case statement.

Comment: Thanks. That is what i am trying to do. I asked that case statement question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234835/sql-insert-into-column-if-condition-is-true Can you answer it there or should i delete that question ?