# Update using case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Given a table:

```
ColumnPosition, ColumnName
   Col 1,          NULL
   Col 2,          NULL
   Col 3,          NULL
```

I want to update `ColumnName` according to a predefined value mapping based on ColumnPosition.

**For example:**
If ColumnPosition = 'Col 1' then update ColumnName to be 'Name'
If ColumnPosition = 'Col 3' then update ColumnName to be 'Address'

How can this be done using CASE statement?

Comment: You don't. You cannot choose the column name in a case.

Comment: I see little logic in wanting to do that. I wouldn't want to do it even in an illogical moment. What problem are you trying to solve with this 'erm solution.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - Its a long story :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean `UPDATE` and not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET ColumnName = CASE WHEN ColumnPosition = 'Col 1' THEN 'Name'
                      WHEN ColumnPosition = 'Col 3' THEN 'Address'
                      -- ... the rest of your conditions
                      ELSE -- put your default value here
                 END
```

Comment: right now, i am writing OO code to generate the 70+ WHEN statements :) This code is going to be big :( unless, conrad's code can be modified to give me the expected output.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of doing a bunch of case statements you could set up a map and then do a join

```
With Map as 
(
    SELECT       'Col 1' ColumnPosition , 'Name' as ColumnName
    UNION SELECT 'Col 3' , 'Address'
 )
UPDATE Table1 
SET Table1.ColumnName = Map.ColumnName
FROM
  table1  
  INNER JOIN MAP 
  ON Table1.ColumnPosition = Map.ColumnPosition;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/524b1/2)

Comment: +1 - I like answers that teach you how to do a better design. Nice one :-)

Comment: thanks, but it did not work as expected. It should set every occurrence of, say Col 3 to Address or whatever you decide. Col 3 occurs multiple times in the column and so do other values.

Comment: @blasto `Col 3` appearing multiple times. [Here's a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ecee/1) where the initial dataset includes dupes on col3. The simplified example is likely missing somthing